# i wanna blink a led with pwm and a potentiometer attached to a ADS1115 modulle using ros2 pubsub package

Tags: ros2, python, publisher, raspberry-pi, subscribers

i had a while ago with some help from this forum sending potentiometer values from a publisher node to a subscriber node to blink a led in pwm but the led doesnt seem to receive values the talker node goes like this:

```
import time
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from time import sleep
from std_msgs.msg import String
from std_msgs.msg import Int64
import board
import busio
import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1115 as ADS
from adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in import AnalogIn
from adafruit_simplemath import map_range
# Create the I2C bus
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

# Create the ADC object using the I2C bus
ads = ADS.ADS1115(i2c)

# Create single-ended input on channel 0
chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0)



# Create differential input between channel 0 and 1
#chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0, ADS.P1)


class Adctalk(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('adctopic')
        self.publisher_= self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)
        self.Adcpub_= self.create_publisher(Int64,'pot',10)
        Adctimer_period = 0.5
        timer_period = 0.5
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.Adctimer = self.create_timer(Adctimer_period, self.knob_callback)
        self.i = 0
    def knob_callback(self):
        while True:
        
         pot =  int(map_range(chan.value,0,4090,0,100))
         Adcmsg= Int64()
        
         Adcmsg.data= pot # ADcmsg.data  = is the pot value now
       
         self.Adcpub_.publish(Adcmsg)
         self.get_logger().info('the adc value is:"%s"' % Adcmsg.data)
         sleep(0.3)
         
        
    def timer_callback(self):

       
        
        msg = String() 
        msg.data= 'adc channel: %s'  % self.i 
     
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info('the string message get shown: "%s"' % msg.data) #publish the potvalue
        self.i += 1

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    adctalk = Adctalk()
    rclpy.spin(adctalk)
    #adctalk.destroy_node
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and then subscribe to:

```
from rclpy.node import Node
from time import sleep
from std_msgs.msg import String, Int64 # i tried it with  Int64 now i got better succes with it
import pwmio # i try the pwm library instead of the digitalio libray
import board
import digitalio

print("hello blinka!")

led = pwmio.PWMOut(board.D21, frequency=5000, duty_cycle=0) # is the pin that the led uses

class MinimalSubscriber(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('adctopic')
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            String,
            'topic',
            self.listener_callback,
            10)
        self.Adcsub = self.create_subscription(
            Int64,
            'pot',
            self.listener_callback,
            10)
        self.Adcsub       
        self.subscription  # prevent unused variable warning
    def Adcsub(self,Adcmsg):   
        led.duty_cycle=Adcmsg.data  # is the value it need to blink
        self.get_logger().info( Adcmsg.data) # is the pot value that needs to be publish
       
        led.duty_cycle = Adcmsg.data # Adcmsg data is the led value that need to go on but it doesnt 
        print("ledvalue is",Adcmsg) # was to check on if it prints
        sleep(0.3)
        
    def listener_callback(self, msg,):
        self.get_logger().info('I heard: "%s"' % msg.data)
       
    
     
        
        

        



def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_subscriber = MinimalSubscriber()

    rclpy.spin(minimal_subscriber)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    minimal_subscriber.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it seem to be correct but it doesnt blink do i have done something wrong?